# Can I force Steam to use secure protocols?

Tags: steam

I'm currently in the middle of an experiment where I [reject insecure outgoing HTTP requests](https://l0b0.wordpress.com/2017/02/25/the-https-only-experience/), and it turns out this breaks Steam in some significant ways:

1. The store page simply displays the following message:

   > Error Code: -102
   >
   > Unable to connect to server. Server may be offline or you may not be connected to the internet.
2. Game updates never get anywhere.

So it appears that both the store and game updates are served through insecure HTTP. This has both security and privacy implications, so I'd like to know if there is any way for me to ***force* Steam to use secure protocols for at least the store and game updates.**

For the record: The Steam client is definitely online, because their support, served over HTTPS, works fine. I've also asked Steam support about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. At the time of writing, navigating to https://store.steampowered.com/ will result in a temporary redirect to http://store.steampowered.com/. I suspect a similar thing will happen for update-urls, but I don't currently have one ready to test with.

Regardless of what sorcery you would perform to upgrade such requests, steam will downgrade those requests again.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't force Steam to use HTTPS. Those URLs give you errors because supporting HTTPS has to be done on the server side, and the necessary support does not exist in the server serving those URLs. There's nothing a client can do to force a non-existent HTTPS server or service to begin existing.

Some Steam pages are secured and accessible via HTTPS (such as https://steamcommunity.com/openid), but these exist due to deliberate creation of HTTPS support for that service. (In that example's case, HTTPS support is necessary for the OpenID service to function.) The existence of some Steam https: URLs does not mean that all http: URLs have https: counterparts.

Comment: The question is not related to how HTTPS works.

Comment: @l0b0 No, but the answer is.